# MDC 102 Flutter Material -- AppBar not showing

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I am following this tutorial from this link
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-102-flutter#3

I am able to do MDC-101 properly , there is no error..

When i started MDC-102 tutorial , appbar needs to be added in this section.
When i add this appbar , it is not showing at all..

My pubspec.yaml file is

```
name: Shrine
description: Learn how to use Material for structure and layout.
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.15.6

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  shrine_images: 1.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  # TODO: Insert Fonts (103)
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/diamond.png
    # TODO: Add slanted menu asset (104)
    - packages/shrine_images/0-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/1-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/2-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/3-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/4-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/5-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/6-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/7-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/8-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/9-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/10-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/11-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/12-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/13-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/14-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/15-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/16-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/17-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/18-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/19-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/20-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/21-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/22-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/23-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/24-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/25-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/26-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/27-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/28-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/29-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/30-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/31-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/32-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/33-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/34-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/35-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/36-0.jpg
    - packages/shrine_images/37-0.jpg
```

I have created another project and there when i add the AppBar , it is showing. I feel that it is related to pubspec.yaml but I cannot find out the problem

My code for home.dart is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
// TODO: Make a collection of cards (102)
// TODO: Add a variable for Category (104)

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: Return an AsymmetricView (104)
// TODO: Pass Category variable to AsymmetricView (104)
return Scaffold(
// TODO: Add app bar (102)
appBar: AppBar(
// TODO: Add buttons and title (102)
leading: IconButton(
icon: Icon(
Icons.menu,
semanticLabel: 'menu',
),
onPressed: () {
print('Menu button');
},
),
title: Text('SHRINE'),
actions: <Widget>[
IconButton(
icon: Icon(
Icons.search,
semanticLabel: 'search',
),
onPressed: () {
print('Search button');
},
),
IconButton(
icon: Icon(
Icons.tune,
semanticLabel: 'filter',
),
onPressed: () {
print('Filter button');
},
),
],
// TODO: Add a grid view (102)

),
body: Center(
child: Text('You did it!'),
),
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I copied your pubspec.yaml and Widget and there were no issues (assuming you actually have *diamonds.png* in your *assets* folder). Perhaps there is another problem.

Comment: Yes there is diamond.png.I have enable web support

Comment: Are you seeing everything but the AppBar?

Comment: There's nothing in what you have shared causing the problem. Please share the rest of your code.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/material-components/material-components-flutter-codelabs.git
cd material-components-flutter-codelabs/mdc_100_series
git checkout 102-starter_and_101-complete

Comment: The above is the started code .. I have changed the AppBar part only in home.dart

Comment: Please clarify. Does nothing show on screen? An error? Everything except the app bar?

Comment: The AppBar is not showing .. Others are showing .. There is no error

Comment: It was a beginner error from my side, this is my first time learning flutter .. This page was the second page, i thought it should load when i run the code. But the main page was loading first, from here i had to navigate.. sorry for all the troubles .. Now it is working ..

Comment: That was going to be my next question after checking out the github. No worries, we've all been there. Good luck on your journey with Flutter.